# Mocha/Chai tests failing because oracledb node module taking too long

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, integration-testing, chai

I have a node web service which initializes an oracledb connection pool. Here is my project structure

### app.ts

```
import { ConnectionDB } from "./dBConnections/DBConnection";
async function initilizeApp(){
try{
    console.log("Initializing Application");

    await Promise.all([ ConnectionDB.initilize() ]);
```

### DBConnection.ts

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');

export class ConnectionDB{

private constructor(){}

static async initilize(){

    try{
        await oracledb.createPool({
            user: USERNAME,
            password: PASSWORD,
            connectString: CONNECTION_STRING,
            poolMin: 20,
            poolMax: 20,
            poolIncrement: 0
        });
```

And in my code in some modules, I call SQL queries directly from the methods like this

### TestController.ts

```
export class TestControllers{

async getSomething(test: IGetSome){

    query = `SELECT * from table;`;

    let getS = await ConnectionDB.executeSimpleQuery(query, bind);
```

Now when I try to run a test which is roughly like this

### testclass.ts

```
import {expect} from 'chai';
import {TestController} from '../src/controllers/TestController';

describe("Sample test ", () => {
it('Simple test', async () => {

  var x = await getSomething(req);
```

I get this error

```
ERROR:ConnectionDB.executeSimpleQuery:Error: NJS-047: poolAlias "default" not found in the connection pool cache
```

and sometimes I see that the call to the query is timing out after 2000ms or something like that.

So my question is 2 parts.

1> Is there a way I can establish the DB connection before the test suite starts running? I have tried a few random things including adding a setup script in mocha.opts but nothing seems to have helped. 
2> If i'm unable to figure out the DB connection part, is there a way I can mock these methods which have the queries so I can avoid running the DB parts?

If i'm going to mock out the DB parts, i'm not sure how the module imports would work because whenever I import the module method from the test and run it, it will run the query by default. Not sure how I can write exhaustive testcases for my code base.

Comment: Why don't you open the connection in the 'before()' block? That would require a little refactoring, i.e. to write another method OpenConnection() and call it...

Comment: I can't remember the exact error but that didn't work for me when I did before(). The problem was that even though I did an await on the DB call, it didn't fully wait for the DB connection and in some cases I got a request timeout.

Comment: The seems to be in connecting to the DB. Not sure what you are using here, but let's say you have back end, does the code in your back end work (not via test, but normal execution)? If it works, check if there are configurations (e.g. connection string in .config file), then make sure that config content is available for the test ...or pass the connection string as parameter...whatever works for you.

Comment: Mocking the DB connection is the better approach (if this is unit-test). Hope someone can help you.

Comment: Getting `NJS-047` means your code is not waiting for the pool to be started before you use it.  Your `promise.all()` looks suspicious.  Regarding overall timing, try decreasing `poolMin` since each connection will cumulatively add to the pool creation time.